# Joining queries and aggregation with elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, join

using ElasticSearch 5.4.2, considering a mapping like this:

```
"mappings": {
    "product": {
        "properties": {
            "enabled": {
                "type": "boolean"
            },
            // etc...
        }
    },
    "cartproduct": {
        "properties": {
            "productId": {
                "type": "keyword"
            },
            // etc...
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to aggregate `cartproduct` by `productId` only for `enabled:true` products.

Currently, I'm doing this. The aggregation works fine, but there's no relation with products (meaning disabled products are aggregated, which is not expected):

```
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "filter": {
            "term": {
                "_type": "cartproduct"
            }
        }
   },
   "aggs": {
       "products": {
            terms: {
                field: 'productId'
            }
       }
   }
}
```

If I try to add `enabled` in this query, it obviously says that the field doesn't exist. But if I search in `product` context, I can't aggregate the result...

Is there a way to achieve this without adding `enabled` in the `cartproduct` document?

Thanks

**edit**

Some documents samples:

```
// product
{
    "_index": "store",
    "_type": "product",
    "_id": "product:8ca2713e",
    "_version": 1,
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
        "categories": [
            10
        ],
        "enabled": true,    <--- MATCH THIS FIELD
        "userinput": false,
        "createdAt": "2017-08-14T16:11:10.182Z",
        "updatedAt": "2017-08-14T16:11:40.978Z",
        "title": "Tart"
    }
}

// cartproduct
{
    "_index": "store",
    "_type": "cartproduct",
    "_id": "cartproduct:6048764d",
    "_version": 1,
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
        "createdAt": "2017-08-16T16:45:39.978Z",
        "productTitle": "Tart",
        "productId": "8ca2713e", <-- AGGREGATE ON THIS FIELD
        "hasComment": false
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post a sample document of both product and cartproduct type?

Answer (score 1):

After some digging and understanding in the doc, I found a working solution:

```
"mappings": {
    // ...
    "cartproduct": {
        "_parent": {
            "type": "product"
        },
        "properties": {
            "productId": {
                "type": "keyword"
            },
            // etc...
        }
    }
}
```

And the search query:

```
{
    "query": {
        "has_parent": {
            "parent_type": "product",
            "query": {
                "term": {
                    "enabled": true
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "products": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "productId"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the exact solution i was going to post but refreshed the page before doing it ;). Basically your problem comes under the category of **joins** and there are 3 possible solutions to it which are discussed here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/joining-queries.html

Answer (score 0):

Why are you restricting your search to only **cartproduct** type? Assuming that you want to aggregate the **productid** throughout the entire index, this type level restriction can be substituted by following to fulfil your requirement.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "enabled": "true"
        }
      }
    },
    "aggs": {
      "products": {
        "terms": {
          "field": "productId"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. I tried that but it doesn't aggregate. I have hits (products that are enabled) but nothing in the "products" aggregation. Did I miss something?

Comment: In fact, hits are "product" documents, but the aggregation field is defined in "cartproduct" documents.